# BizTalk EDI 850 Purchase Order - Where to put Gift Message items

Tags: edi, purchase-order

I need to send three fields related to a gift-card to a vendor so they can print these items on a packing slip for shipping.  We already have the 850 working, just need to find the best place to send these: Recipient, From, and Message. Our web site allows the user to enter these, so for example the recipient will not always be the name on the ship-to name.

The requirement is to print something like this on the packing slip:

To: Dearest Opie
From: Aunt Bee
Love on your Birthday.

Looks like some people us SAC15.

SAC02 has a plethora of codes for example:

A010
A020
A030
etc...

BizTalk itself doesn't tell you what any of these codes mean.  Is there some EDI standard somewhere online that is free to access? How do I pick the proper code? 
I have downloaded several public 850 from other companies for ideas, but most of them don't mention gift cards.

I could send the recipient in one SAC15 with code 1 in SAC02, the to in another SAC15 in another segment with code 2, and a similar for the message (which might be over 80 characters have might have to put on multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

THe X12 standard isn't published for free, but there is EDI Notepad from Liaison / OpenText that you can download and look at it.  For this application, you can add MSG segments to your output.  These are mostly free form, but you can add three of them to handle your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, went with the SAC15 and just picked some SAC02 codes. So where does one buy "the standard" and how much does it cost.  Seems like most people just do it based on experience and samples from what I've seen.

Comment: it's typically expensive.  http://store.x12.org/store/  that's why there's very little in the way of open source parsers that have syntax / standards validation.  that's also part of the reason there's so much bastardization.